# Confused with an article on likelihood estimation from incomplete data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, missing-data

I was reading an article [Learning from Incomplete Data](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/foo.pdf), and was confused about a simple thing. Specifically, authors take a detour to show that 
$P(X^o, R \mid \theta, \phi) = P(R \mid X^o, \phi) \cdot P(X^o \mid \theta)$, where $\theta$ are the parameters for generating process for $X^o$, and $\phi$ for the missing value mechanism for $R$.

Why shouldn't it hold in all cases? Namely,

$P(X^o, R \mid \theta, \phi) = P(X^o \mid \theta, \phi) \cdot P(R \mid X^o, \theta, \phi)$ by "chain rule", and since $X^o$ depends only on $\theta$, and $R$ on $\phi$, we can write it as $P(X^o \mid \theta) \cdot P(R \mid X^o, \phi)$.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't hold in all cases for which $X$ depends only on $\theta$?

Comment: So I do think that this should hold in all cases, but the article includes another variable ($X^m$) in the calculations, and makes this equality conditional. That is the part I am confused with. This refers to the derivation of equation-2 on page 3 in the linked article.